# Can Publish Transaction be updated via core service?

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service, publishing, publishtransaction

Just for discussion's sake, I am interested can any of the properties of publish transaction be updated via core service?
client.Update() method does work with PublishTransactionData object, however, it throws an error that changed property is read-only. This is completely OK, since transactions should not be changed because of the consistency of publishing. But what interests me is something that we CAN change about transaction?

For example, we have sent 1 million of items in queue under high priority so instead of deleting and re-sending them on low, we just want to update publish transaction publish priority. Is something like that even possible via core service?

Comment: If you want to play a bit with the publish transaction, you may want to explore the Storage Extension

Comment: I believe only way to do it with core service is to remove and add the comp again in the queue with desired priority. There is a reason why publish transactions' properties can not be set as they are locked with deployer service and can not be modified in a zip package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.  We had a similar case where we needed to increase the priority of some items in the queue.

I tried similar in 2011 but used `Save` and not `Update`.  It threw a similar error message (can't remember, but it was most likely the same).

Since ours were occasional one off cases, we just ended up doing it via the GUI, but it looks to me like you'll end up having to write a utility to read the transaction, delete it and create a new one with the new priority, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to update publish priority of transactions via core service. You can update it directly over database, but you also need to update queue messages table so that publisher picks it up. No need to say that this is not supported.